# At the Pods code , how to get the file under the Resources?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

In the file XYShareBtnView.m ,I want to get image in the Resources,how can I do this? TKS!

I want to make a pod , But I do not know How to get the Resource.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a need for you to pass the path of the image. Just try accessing the image normally using the name of the image.

**Objective-C:**

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIImage(string:"imagename")
```